# How to convert mysql query to laravel query builder

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-5, query-builder

Is there any way to convert following query to laravel query builder?

```
select `employee_id`
from `otc_employee_qualifications` 
where `emp_qualifctn_type` IN ('29','27') 
group by `employee_id`
having count(Distinct `emp_qualifctn_type`) = 2
```

[image]

Comment: do u need to know how to write query for laravel or you want to write code to automatically create query for laravel from given query??

Comment: i want to just convert that query to laravel query builder. thats all.

Comment: you can have an idea ...visit http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries

Comment: What you have tried so far? Post your attempts. If you simply tried to search  Laravel Query Builder then you simply get the docs too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try as below :

```
$users = DB::table('otc_employee_qualifications')
         ->select('employee_id')
         ->whereIn('emp_qualifctn_type', [27,29])
         ->groupBy('employee_id')
         ->having(DB::raw("count(Distinct emp_qualifctn_type)"), '=', 2)
         ->get();
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'employee_id,DB::raw("distinct' in 'field list' (SQL: select `employee_id,DB::raw("distinct` as `as` from `otc_employee_qualifications` where `emp_qualifctn_type` in (27, 29) group by `employee_id` having `counter` = 2)

Comment: Convert `->select('employee_id,DB::raw("distinct emp_qualifctn_type as counter'))` into `->select('employee_id',DB::raw("distinct emp_qualifctn_type as counter"))`

Comment: You're Welcome. @AG21

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'distinct emp_qualifctn_type as counter from `otc_employee_qualifications` where ' at line 1 (SQL: select `employee_id`, distinct emp_qualifctn_type as counter from `otc_employee_qualifications` where `emp_qualifctn_type` in (27, 29) group by `employee_id` having `emp_qualifctn_type` = 2)

Comment: @JishadP please check your `having` clause

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'distinct emp_qualifctn_type as counter from `otc_employee_qualifications` where ' at line 1 (SQL: select `employee_id`, distinct emp_qualifctn_type as counter from `otc_employee_qualifications` where `emp_qualifctn_type` in (27, 29) group by `employee_id` having `counter` = 2)

Comment: $empsarr = DB::table('otc_employee_qualifications')
                ->select('employee_id',DB::raw("distinct emp_qualifctn_type as counter"))
                ->whereIn('emp_qualifctn_type', [27,29])
                ->groupBy('employee_id')
                ->having('counter', '=', 2)
                ->get();

Comment: added phpmyadmin in question. please check.

Comment: @JishadP, please check updated `select()`. You should get result now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95665/discussion-between-jishad-p-and-ag21).

Comment: how to convert mysql query to laravel , "select * from `officer_availabilities` where `officer_id` = 52 and 1 BETWEEN start_day AND end_day"

Answer (score -2):

Answer:

```
  DB::select('employee_id')
        ->from('otc_employee_qualifications')
        ->whereIn('emp_qualifctn_type', ('29', '27'))
        ->groupBy('employee_id')
        ->having(DB::raw('count(Distinct emp_qualifctn_type)'), '=', 2)
        ->get();
```

You can convert SQL query into laravel eloquent query by using bellow website.

This will convert SQL query to laravel eloquent base query

[Convert SQL query to Eloquent base query](http://www.midnightcowboycoder.com/)

Comment: how to convert, this query to laravel  "select * from `officer_availabilities` where `officer_id` = 52 and 1 BETWEEN start_day AND end_day"